# How to limit the number of results in a list within a relationship in spring-data

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data, named-query

I'm studying Spring Data, and I have a question about a query.

I have a relationship between two entities:

```
@Entity
public class A {
   //other fields
   List<B> counter;
   //getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class B {
  //other fields
  Long count;
  //getters and setters
}
```

Now, in my repository for class A, I would like to get All objects of A. For each one of these objects, I want to get just the first five objects from class B ordered by the field "count" asc or desc.

How can I do it? The examples of "first 5 elements" or "top 5 elements" I've found would only be useful for elements of entity A and not from B.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**
Maybe it's possible to use a named query as well. If someone has an idea of how to follow this way and could help, I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this. I hope this works for you. 
**@BatchSize** can be used to define size for batch loading of collections or lazy entities.

```
@Entity
public class A {
   //other fields
   @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
   @BatchSize(size = 10)
   List<B> counter;
   //getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class B {
  //other fields
  Long count;
  //getters and setters
}
```

**Fetching Strategies**

There are four fetching strategies

1. fetch-“join” = Disable the lazy loading, always load all the collections and entities.
2. fetch-“select” (default) = Lazy load all the collections and entities.
3. batch-size=”N” = Fetching up to ‘N’ collections or entities, *Not record*.
4. fetch-“subselect” = Group its collection into a sub select statement.

**batch-size=”10″ or @BatchSize(size = 10)**
The batch-size fetching strategy is not define how many records inside in the collections are loaded. Instead, it defines how many collections should be loaded.

Please find the link: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-fetching-strategies-examples/

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work. I think it should be done in the repository of class A, you know? Instead of using the findAll() method, maybe there's some way to filter how many results I want for that specific list.
 
But anyway, thanks for your response.